# AMP Doesn't Render All Images

Tags: html, css, mobile, amp-html

I had some issues with AMP by using overflow-scroll element. Seems like it doesn't display the whole images when i resize my browser to mobile view.

Here are the example : 
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/43663127/46241046-b6ffa580-c3e3-11e8-9924-d3790bb756fb.jpg

I use the AMP template by AMP Start https://www.ampstart.com/templates.

I hope someone can help me into fixing this issue or maybe other workaround.

Thanks !

Comment: I hope someone can help .

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.